# composer repositories, после установки не видит пакет

Tags: php, github, composer

Всем привет, в первый раз устанавливаю через `composer` библиотеку из `github`.

В composer.json написал следующее:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@test.ru"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:user_name/simple-class.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "symfony/var-dumper": "v4.3.5",
        "test/test-test": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

После `composer update` все прошло успешно, и библиотека загрузилась в папку `vendor`.

В библиотеке всего 1 файл с классом (не учитывая файл с лицензией, README и .git).
Структура следующая:

`vendor/user_name/simple-class-dir/simple-class/src/ClassName.php`

при попытке обратиться к классу из файла, указывая namespace из файла, то php не видит этот класс и неймспейс.

Название неймспейса и класса соответствует директории и файлу, по psr-4.

Подскажите пожалуйста. В чем может быть проблема? Может каике-то настройки композера еще надо ставить? Другие библиотеки из packegist загружается сразу.

Comment: `require_once './vendor/autoload.php'` сделали в своем index.php или в скрипте который запускается?

Comment: А можете ClassName показать?

Comment: или ссылку дать, и какая ошибка появляется?

Comment: Вы use прописали в скрипте своем и какая ошибка отдается?

Comment: Но класс то `toecto\AMQPSimpleWrappe\AMQPSimpleWrapper` то есть должно быть `use toecto\AMQPSimpleWrappe\AMQPSimpleWrapper` и `new AMQPSimpleWrapper()` или просто `new toecto\AMQPSimpleWrappe\AMQPSimpleWrapper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По чату пример использования

```
$mrq = new toecto\AMQPSimpleWrappe\AMQPSimpleWrapper();
```

или же

```
<?php

namespace 'test';

use toecto\AMQPSimpleWrappe\AMQPSimpleWrapper;

$mrq = new AMQPSimpleWrapper();
```

Comment: @asdfasda не за что.